# Is there a way to react to a local Sqlite being updated via Azure Mobile Services sync?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm writing an Xamarin iOS app, which will display a mobile graphical dashboard.
I'm planning on handling data delivery and synchronization (as well as offline scenario) by using Azure Mobile Services to sync my local Sqlite data on a regular intervals (let's say every 10 minutes). Is there a way to react to the sync finishing by refreshing the UI?

Comment: mobile services or mobile apps?  The SDKs are similar, but have slightly different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is to implement `IMobileServicesSyncHandler`. This lets you override these events and respond to them, to refresh the UI, etc. This is the same place you can handle conflict resolution, etc.

I think [this guy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2014/04/07/deep-dive-on-the-offline-support-in-the-azure-mobile-service-managed-client-sdk.aspx) shows some good examples.